# Check if an Object contains any value for the Same key in a Different Object JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry for the Lost Post . The problem statement

I have this URL -

http://www.XXXXX.com/mobiles-tablets/mobiles/apple?q=&idx=letsTango_default_products&p=0&hFR%5Bcategories.level0%5D%5B0%5D=Mobiles%20%26%20Tablets%20%2F%2F%2F%20Mobiles%20%2F%2F%2F%20Apple&nR%5Bprice.AED.default%5D%5B%3C%3D%5D%5B0%5D=2560&is_v=1

I had to extract all the query-params in a object like a key value pair .

and then check from a different object if any of these query-params with same key has any matching value .

This is my solution , I am new to java script and so i want to confirm if this is the right way to go about.
The solution so far works for all the cases . just let me know if the performance can be enhanced or any better way.

Fiddle Link for the Solution - http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsingh09/tqpzv/6/

code

```
var callingUrl = "http://www.letstango.com/mobiles-tablets/mobiles/apple?q=&idx=letsTango_default_products&fsrc=sort_price,brand&p=0&hFR%5Bcategories.level0%5D%5B0%5D=Mobiles%20%26%20Tablets%20%2F%2F%2F%20Mobiles%20%2F%2F%2F%20LG&nR%5Bprice.AED.default%5D%5B%3C%3D%5D%5B0%5D=2560&nR%5Bprice.AED.default%5D%5B%3E%3D%5D%5B0%5D=1138&is_v=1";

if (callingUrl) {
  var queryParam = {};
  var split = callingUrl.split("?");
  if (split.length > 1) {
    var query = split[1].split("&");
    if (query.length > 1) {
      _.each(query, function(q) {
        var key = decodeURIComponent(q.split("=")[0]);
        var value = decodeURIComponent(q.split("=")[1]);
        if (value.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
          value = value.split(",");
        }
        queryParam[key] = value;
      })
    }
  }
}

if (!_.isEmpty(queryParam)) {
  var value = {
    "fsrc": ["brand"]
  };
  for (var key in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      for (var k in queryParam) {
        if (queryParam.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
          if (k === key) {
            var index = _.intersection(value[key], queryParam[k]);
            if (index.length > 0) {
              console.log("Matches");
            } else {
              console.log("fails");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

please note - the url can change depending upon the browser url.

Thanks in advance , I want to get the best performance possible for this problem.

Comment: What is your question? The script outputs `"Matches" "Matches"`

Comment: I am just console logging it now . i want to check if the method i have written i the correct way to solve this and also check the performance @Halcyon.
If this will work for any url with any type of query params